# Searching for object in another list jinja

Tags: django, jinja2

I have a django templates set up. My view is passing two lists that are queries. Let's call the first one masterList and the second one temp.

I want to search and see if an object in masterList is in temp. If it is, i want to render a different button on my template. Or else, go with the usual. Here is what I have:

My temp model has this:

```
masterItem = ForeignKey(masterList, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
..
..
```

My template:

```
 {% for s in masterList %}
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{s.id}}</th>
                <td>{{s.user.username}}</td>
                <td>{{s.user.email}}</td>
                <td>{{s.major}}</td>
                {% if s in temp %}
                    <td><a type="button" class="btn btn-success disabled">Email Sent</a></td>
                {% else %}
              
                    <td><a type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'secretPage' s.student_id%}">Promote</a></td>
                {% endif %}
               
            </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I understand that if statement doesn't work because I am searching for one type of object in another. So what's the best way to do it.

Comment: I am no expert in this. Maybe someone more experienced can chime in. But does that list have a keys() method that you can call and search through that? Or is that for dictionaries only